# Join column must be defined with the same insertable and updatable attributes

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i upgraded to  spring boot 3.2.1 (that use hibernate 6.4.1)

I get this error since this upgrade when i try to boot application

> Join column 'query_type_id' on collection property
> 'com.acme.demo.common.QueryType.queryStatus' must be defined with the
> same insertable and updatable attributes

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table
public class QueryType {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long QueryTypeId;

    private String code;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "queryType")
    private Set<Query> queries = new HashSet<>(0);

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "QUERY_STATUS_TYPE", schema = "", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "QUERY_TYPE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "QUERY_STATUS_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<QueryStatus> queryStatus = new HashSet<>(0);

}

@Data
@Entity
@Table
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "QUERYTYPE_CODE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class QueryStatus {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    private Long queryStatusId;

    private String code;

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "queryStatus")
    private Set<Query> queries = new HashSet<>(0);

}
```

i have some class who extends QueryStatus

I just don't understand why i get this error suddendly

that worked fine with spring boot 3.2.0 (that use hibernate 6.3.1)

Answer (score 2):

You can probably remove the `updatable` since in previous versions it wouldn't prevent the adding or removing of members of the relationship.

```
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "QUERY_TYPE_ID", nullable = false ) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "QUERY_STATUS_ID", nullable = false)
```

If your intention is to make the relationship readonly, than you need to add both `insertable=false` and `updatable=false`

```
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "QUERY_TYPE_ID", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "QUERY_STATUS_ID", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
```

This is based on the responses from the related Hibernate ticket https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17586

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Framework sometimes changes suddenly and unexpectedly and for the most part it is really for the best. I keep track of all of these things so I thought I'd share my experience with you on this exact problem. So it started with this code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bridge_opening_conflicts")
data class BridgeOpeningConflict(
    @Id
    val message: String? = null,

    @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinColumn(name = "bridge_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    val relatedOpeningTime: List<BridgeOpeningTime>? = null
)
```

Where they have standardized the usage of `@JoinColumn` and so now we need in this case to wrap it around `@JoinTable` for `@ManyToMany` relations like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bridge_opening_conflicts")
data class BridgeOpeningConflict(
    @Id
    val message: String? = null,

    @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "bridge_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)])
    val relatedOpeningTime: List<BridgeOpeningTime>? = null
)
```

This didn't solve the problem just yet and then I got the same error you are reporting in this question, which makes some sense, but I also do not understand the constraint real case possible usage completely. I didn't see it before and I'm not sure if it was by accident that the Spring framework had ignored this before, but the problem came from that. Although I had defined `updatable` as false, I didn't configure `insertable` at all and reliad on its default value. But both need to be the same in this case. Both properties are `true` by default so this meant that I had `updatable` as false, but `insertable` as true. For my project, adding `insertable` and setting it to false fixed my problem:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
@JoinTable(joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "bridge_id", nullable = true, updatable = false, insertable = false)])
val relatedOpeningTime: List<BridgeOpeningTime>? = null
```

I later set them both to true. If you look at the `JoinColumn` annotation implementation in the Jakarta's `persistence-api` that Spring uses you'll notice that they are indeed both set to true by default:

```
@Repeatable(JoinColumns.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface JoinColumn {
    String name() default "";

    String referencedColumnName() default "";

    boolean unique() default false;

    boolean nullable() default true;

    boolean insertable() default true;

    boolean updatable() default true;

    String columnDefinition() default "";

    String table() default "";

    ForeignKey foreignKey() default @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.PROVIDER_DEFAULT);
}
```

You can find my complete example here: [Domain Example](https://github.com/jesperancinha/bridges-surveillance-story/tree/master/bl-central-server/bl-domain-repository/src/main/kotlin/org/jesperancinha/logistics/jpa/dao)

In your case in specific you just need to add `insertable` to every single joinColumn you are using and make it false like this:

```
@JoinTable(name = "QUERY_STATUS_TYPE", schema = "", 
  joinColumns = { 
      @JoinColumn(name = "QUERY_TYPE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false) }, 
  inverseJoinColumns = { 
      @JoinColumn(name = "QUERY_STATUS_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false) })
```